# How to show control panel of video tag when click video

Tags: html, video

I hid control panel of video on mobile using this "video::-webkit-media-controls-panel{display:none}" in responsive.css because it occupy the height of video.
But I want to show the control panel when user click the video screen.
How can I make it? Any help would be appreciated.
than you

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the shadow DOM, have you tried making controls visible or not - in this instance they're hidden by default but get shows when the user clicks and hidden when the user mouses out (could trigger on a click elsewhere, or when the video starts playing for instance)

```
<video width="400" controls id="video" onclick="mox(true);" onmouseout="mox(false);">
    <source src="bigbuck.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<script>
// get the video element
var video = document.getElementById("video");

// attach a listener to hide controls when video starts playing
// note: you probably want some more logic to make this a more usable experience
video.addEventListener('playing', mox(false),false);

// hides the controls
mox(false)

function mox(s) {
    if (s) {
        video.controls = "controls";
    } else {
        video.controls = "";
    }
}
</script>
```